# MouseDown event not working on whole container

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

My Problem is when `mousedown` event occurs in right button i need to check whether there is any `div` if not then my `flag` global `variable` becomes false but i am not getting that condition.

My jQuery script is as follow.

```
var flag = true;
   $(document).mousedown(function(event){
            if( event.button == 2 ) {
                if ($(event.target).parent().is('.draggable')){
                    $el = $(event.target).parent();
                    flag = true;    
                }else{
                 flag = false;          
            }   
        }
    });
```

jsp code:

```
<div class="main">    
<div class="draggable" >
        <a href="#"><div class="inside"></div></a>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The event must have been prevented from bubbling `:/` with `event.stopPropagation()`. Note that _event.which also normalizes button presses (mousedown and mouseupevents), reporting 1 for left button, 2 for middle, and 3 for right. Use event.which instead of event.button._

Comment: you need to add another parent div

Comment: @patilharshal16 can you please put some sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this I think there is need of one more parent. Hope it will work.
Since I was stuck with same problem few months ago.

```
$(document).mousedown(function(event){
                if( event.button == 2 ) {
                    if ($(event.target).parent().parent().is('.draggable')){
                        $el = $(event.target).parent().parent();
                        flag = true;    
                    }else{
                     flag = false;          
                }   
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is using closest() method since the structure may be different sometimes

So your code could be like

```
$('mousedown',function(event){
    var $draggable;
    if( event.which == 2 ) {
        $dragable = $(event.target).closest('.draggable');
        if ($dragable.length){
            $el = $dragable;
            flag = true;    
         }else{
             flag = false;          
         }   
    }
});
```

Note that event.which also normalizes button presses (mousedown and mouseupevents), reporting 1 for left button, 2 for middle, and 3 for right. Use event.which instead of event.button

### EDIT

Using `parent` method means that there will always exist exactly two ancestors in between. Relying on strict structures leads to rigidity and bug prone code. IMO, using `closest` method in place of `parent` for such a case is a better approach.